# How to compare two hexadecimal numbers

Tags: c#, .net, string, hex, compare

What is the best way to compare two hexadecimal numbers (that is a string)? For instance,

```
string a = "3F";
string b = "32";

if (a > b)
   MessageBox.Show("a is greater");
```

Should work. (Assuming > has been properly overloaded).

Comment: Your method won't work if there are variations in the formats, e.g., `"0x3F" < "32"` and `"3f" < "3A"`.   You should let the built-in system conversion routines deal with the complexities of representing hex values as strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always convert them to ints and compare them that way:

```
int a = int.Parse("3E", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
int b = int.Parse("32", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

if (a > b)
    MessageBox.Show("a is greater");
```

Seems safer :)

Comment: While this fits the OPs scenario, it breaks down if the hex string exceeds 4 bytes (or 8 bytes for long).

Answer (score 3):

Convert them to integers and compare the integers.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a simple algo based on String comparisson:
Assumed your numbers have a unique format: always lower case or higher case letters. Leading 0x or not, no leading zeros. Then you can do like this:
If number a has more digits than number b: a > b

If the number of digits is equal you could use String.Compare.

This algo has the advantage it is not limited to 32 or 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly robust implementation of hendrik’s suggestion.  There are a number of ways it could be optimized if your input strings have known attributes, but it should be able to compare valid hex strings of any size and/or with mixed formats.

```
public int HexStringCompare(string value1, string value2)
{
    string InvalidHexExp = @"[^\dabcdef]";
    string HexPaddingExp = @"^(0x)?0*";
    //Remove whitespace, "0x" prefix if present, and leading zeros.  
    //Also make all characters lower case.
    string Value1 = Regex.Replace(value1.Trim().ToLower(), HexPaddingExp, "");
    string Value2 = Regex.Replace(value2.Trim().ToLower(), HexPaddingExp, "");

    //validate that values contain only hex characters
    if (Regex.IsMatch(Value1, InvalidHexExp))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Value1 is not a hex string");
    }
    if (Regex.IsMatch(Value2, InvalidHexExp))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Value2 is not a hex string");
    }

    int Result = Value1.Length.CompareTo(Value2.Length);
    if (Result == 0)
    {
        Result = Value1.CompareTo(Value2);
    }

    return Result;
}
```

Using this to answer the OP's question:

```
if (HexStringCompare(a, b) > 0)
   MessageBox.Show("a is greater");
```