# Compare string representation of a hexadecimal number

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, compare

I follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-how-to-order-connection-state-events#prerequisites. There is example but in JavaScript without strong typing.

As a `sequenceNumber` I have

```
string newSequenceNumber = "000000000000000001D8122A784F747C00000005000000000000000000000007";
string oldSequenceNumber = "000000000000000001D8122A784F747C00000005000000000000000000000006";
```

I need to compare these values to find out if `new` is grater than `old`.
How to convert that value to decimal type and compare?

I've tried this code but no success

```
decimal newVal = decimal.Parse(newSequenceNumber);
```

Comment: Note that the accepted answer of the duplicate will not work for you since the numbers are too big to be converted to integers (or decimals without losing precision), but the [string-comparison technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15638355/1081897) should work.

Comment: @DStanley It doesn't work: The number style AllowHexSpecifier is not supported on floating point data types.  for `decimal a = decimal.Parse(newSequenceNumber, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);` What do you mean by " string-comparison technique"? As you can see my numbers have always the same length. I'm not sure this is a duplicate

Comment: @DStanley Please don't close it, help me to solve the problem because this is not a duplicate

Comment: that hex string is too big for a decimal. You can;t parse it to a decimal or an integer. If you just want to see which one is bigger, then a string comparison will work. The string that is "greater" (in alphabetical order) will represent the larger number